# Running shell script that replace content in texfile

Tags: string, macos, shell, replace

What I want to achieve is that I replace some placeholder inside all *.txt files of one folder.

I don't really often use shell scripts, but for this purpose I want to use it. My first try was this:

```
#!/bin/sh
MYSTRING="Thesedentary"
echo $MYSTRING
perl -pi -w -e 's/{{PLACEHOLDER}}/${MYSTRING}/g;' /path_to_directory/*.txt
```

I know that `perl -pi -w -e 's/.../.../g;' /path_to_directory/*.txt` will replace the content of the first `/.../` with the second `/.../` but as you can see I want to replace the second `/.../` with the content of an variable -> `MYSTRING`. All I get is this:

```
Name "main::MYSTRING" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
```

But the `{{PLACEHOLDER}}` in the files will be replaced with nothing ->

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
#!/bin/sh
MYSTRING='Thesedentary'
eval "perl -pi -w -e 's/{{TEST}}/${MYSTRING}/g;' /path_to_directory/*.js"
```

use `eval` to execute the command.